# what is net.trainParam.mu in NNtoolbox, should i change this parameter？

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

when I am using "trainbr", it always came out with "maximum mu reached".
 what does this mean？ should i change this parameter？

Answer (score 1):

> When using trainbr, it is important to let the algorithm run until the effective number of parameters has converged. The training might stop with the message "Maximum MU reached." This is typical, and is a good indication that the algorithm has truly converged.

This is what [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html) says.